# PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting

Tags: visual-studio-code, php-7

I'm running windows 10 fresh copy and I just installed visual studio code.
I was trying to develop a PHP project using VS Code.
But I'm having trouble in setting up the environment.

I saw a blog post and I downloaded the binary file of PHP 7 and place it in the "C" drive. Then I set path variable too.

But still, I'm getting this issue.

[image]

Comment: Add your folder where your php.exe is to your Windows PATH variable. I edited 'user configuratio' in VS Code but it didn't help. After that I added php folder to my PATH variable and now it works.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You installed `PHP IntelliSense` extension, and this error because of it.
So if you want to fix this problem go to this menu:
`File -> Preferences -> Settings`
Now you can see 2 window. In the right window add below codes:

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.0.4\\php.exe",
    "php.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.0.4\\php.exe"
}
```

Just like below image.
[image]
**NOTICE:** This address `C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.0.4\\php.exe` is my `php7.exe` file address. Replace this address with own `php7.exe`.

Comment: Sadly even after doing this the issue continued :/

Comment: @Jhollman  Did you aware of double black slash ? Did you use exactly ? My problem get solved after using this two code lines.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using php-7.2.4-nts-Win32-VC15-x64 in “C:\php” folder and my user settings had just “php.validate.enable”, “php.validate.executablePath” and “php.validate.run”. PHP validation started working when I added the “php.executablePath” config. Now, in my environment the user settings are as follows:
`{    "php.executablePath":  "C:/php/php.exe",    "php.validate.enable": true,    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/php/php.exe",    "php.validate.run": "onType" }`.

Comment: Is it possible/safe to do this with an external server? what if run php not locally but in a server?

Comment: can this be done for an external server? I mean, what if my php bin files live in an external server? I tried to set up the executable path but had no luck

Comment: For those Xampp user and has multiple php version installed can see the running php version using the **click on explorer it will open up the exact folder of xampp installed folder > php folder**  .

Comment: escaping slash helps ! that's what was missing even after i entered the path.

Comment: For some reason, if you put PHP in your PATH and have the "php.executablePath" & "php.validate.executablePath" previously set then you'll get this exact error.
After testing PHP with "php -v" and confirming it's in the PATH the only fix I could come up was removing the "php.executablePath" & "php.validate.executablePath" from the settings.json.

Comment: can I use shortcut for this?

Answer (score 51):

For those who are using **xampp**:

*File -> Preferences -> Settings*

```
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
"php.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
```

Answer (score 13):

This one also works

1. Remove the **"php.executablePath"** line from the VS code settings.
2. Then add the **xampp** **php** path to the **System variables**

[image]

[image]

After that restart the Visual Studio Code

Answer (score 6):

After adding php directory in User Settings,

```
{
    "php.validate.executablePath": "C:/phpdirectory/php7.1.8/php.exe",
    "php.executablePath": "C:/phpdirectory/php7.1.8/php.exe"
}
```

If you still have this error, please verify you have installed :

- 64-bit or 32-bit version of php (x64 or x86), depending on your OS;
- some librairies like Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145;

To test if you PHP exe is ok, open cmd.exe :

```
c:/prog/php-7.1.8-Win32-VC14-x64/php.exe --version
```

If PHP fails, a message will be prompted with the error (missing dll for example).

Comment: Please, do not post your code as an image. Use markdown instead.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this !!!. This will solve your problem for sure!**

**Method 1 -**

Step 1 - Go to '**Environmental Variables**'.

Step 2 - Find **PATH** variable and add the path to your PHP folder.

Step 3 - For '**XAMPP**' users put 'C:\xampp\php' and '**WAMP**' users put 'C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.1.9' ) and save.

**Method 2-**

In **VS Code**

> File -> Preferences -> Settings.

[image]

Open '**settings.json**' file and put the below codes.

If you are using **WAMP** put this code and Save.

```
  "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.1.9\\php.exe",
  "php.executablePath": "C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.1.9\\php.exe"
```

If you are using **XAMPP** put this code and Save.

```
  "php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
  "php.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
```

Note - Replace **php7.1.9** with your PHP version.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `macOS`, you need to install `php`. You can install it via [brew](https://brew.sh/) executing the following commands on the terminal:

```sh
brew tap homebrew/core

brew install php
```

After that, you can open `VS Code` and the error will disappear

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu 20.04 the path to executable php is

List all available paths:
`$ whereis php`

One of the paths is:
`/usr/bin/php`

More details on where to add this path:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php

Answer (score 2):

For me it was important to delete the "php.executablePath" path from the VS code settings and leave only the path to PHP in the Path variable.

When I had the Path variable together with php.executablePath, an irritating error still occurred (despite the fact that the path to php was correct).

Comment: Same here, it's the only thing that worked in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For me this setting was working.
In my windows 8.1 the path for php7 is

> C:\user\test\tools\php7\php.exe

settings.json

```
 {  
 "php.executablePath":"/user/test/tools/php7/php.exe",
 "php.validate.executablePath": "/user/test/tools/php7/php.exe"
 }
```

see also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/533

Answer (score 0):

in 2022, I had the same issue - my solution was to set the
*php.executablePath* and *php.validate.executablePath* to use the folder **only** (with a trailing slash), omitting the actual executable 'php.exe'.

Answer (score 0):

Well , Everyone has added their answer but I will add one more thing that the chosen answer didn't update.

You can add multiple php executables now ( if [code runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension installed  )

A similar issue was pointed out in vscode's github repo [#128098](https://www.github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128098) and in [#131534](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131534) and it was addressed after

**VS Code version**:  *1.59.1*  [[3866c35]](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/131534)
**Release Date**   : *19th August 2021* or *2021-08-19T11:57:20.140Z*

Anyway, so you can now :

- add your multiple versions/installations of php by clicking on the bottom status bar of vscode, specifically on the version of php you are running ( in this example it is 7.4.3) 
  [image: bottom bar of vscode]
- or by editing the code runner extension settings in `settings.json`(both point to the same file)

`settings.json` File path in windows and samplecontents: 
`C:\Users\{Your Name}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\settings.json`

```json
"[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": true,
    "debug.onTaskErrors": "showErrors",
    "redhat.telemetry.enabled": false,
    "[cpp]": {
        "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": true,
        "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace",
        "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true
    },
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "totalTypeScript.hideAllTips": false,
    "totalTypeScript.hideBasicTips": false,
    "files.associations": {
        "*.inc": "php"
    },
    "php.executables": {
        "7.4.3":"C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
        "8.1":"C:\\xampp\\php8\\php.exe"
    }
}
```

Just add

```json
    "php.executables": {
            "7.4.3":"C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
        }
```

Or

```json
"php.executables": {
            "7.4.3":"C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
            "8.1":"C:\\xampp\\php8\\php.exe"
        }
```

at the bottom of your `settings.json` file in vs code

Answer (score 0):

Update (for xampp):

This one worked for me at settings.json add this code:

```
{
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
 // "php.executablePath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
 "phpserver.phpPath": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe",
}
```

doesn't really need the executablePath as other's have mentioned so I omitted it and I added the phpserver.phpPath

Answer (score 0):

### macOS users

Extending [pableiros's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71539543/1394387) here's bit  more in-depth explanation for macOS beginner users.

For macOS users who do not have homebrew installed install with [homebrew's installation instructions](https://brew.sh/) then follow along below.

For macOS users who do not have homebrew's php formulae installed follow [pableiros's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71539543/1394387) or [brew's command here](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/php#default) then follow along below.

For macOS users that now have or had brew's php formulae already installed and the notification error persists, open terminal app find your brew install executable application path: by running terminal command `which php`:

**returns**

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/php
```

**Now add that path to your json settings**

```
{
    "php.executablePath": "/opt/homebrew/bin/php"
}
```