# VSCode: PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

friends!
I'm getting this error (see title) after the attempt to install PHP IntelliSense v2.3.10 for VS Code editor v1.37.1. I don't have PHP installed. I use the Open Server v5.3.0 Ultimate with activated PHP7.1-x64 support.

This here does not look exactly like my case. [PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287927/php-executable-not-found-install-php-7-and-add-it-to-your-path-or-set-the-php-e)

And I cannot see the window where to put in the 2 lines mentioned in the [PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287927/php-executable-not-found-install-php-7-and-add-it-to-your-path-or-set-the-php-e).

Please tell me what to do.

Comment: :-? ... Do you mean [this](https://i.imgur.com/cMpnXDz.png)?

Answer (score 3):

It's easy to fix.
First you need to find where your php executable file is located, it's called `php.exe`

For example I'm using laragon : `E:/laragon/bin/php/php-7.2.19-Win32-VC15-x64/php.exe`

So all what you need is find this location and then go to `file=>preferences=>settings` and search for `settings.json` 
then open it and add this line

`"php.validate.executablePath": "your php .exe path"`
and of course you need to add this line carefuly and respect json format rules

Comment: What if I don't have php.exe on my computer? I'm using Open Server as localhost.

Comment: @Mikhail If you don't have PHP installed then you cannot use this extension. Its [marketplace page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense) states: "The language server [...] is implemented purely in PHP". Plus, its strange to develop code in any given language if you don't have the language compiler/interpreter available.