# Vs code showing php not found

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, path

> PHP executable not found. Install PHP and add it to your PATH or set the php.debug.executablePath settings source php debug

When I try to run any code it doesn't run - it shows this error, but I had run code in VS Code earlier and it used to run. I tried to install php but still it shows this.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40287927/php-executable-not-found-install-php-7-and-add-it-to-your-path-or-set-the-php-e)

Comment: No i tried it shows the same

Answer (score 0):

Check this way for fix your problem :
https://nick.af/articles/fix-php-executable-not-found-error-in-vs-code

How to fix PHP executable not found error in VS Code

```
Install php on your computer (e.g. with XAMPP)
Locate your php installation directory
Open Advanced System Settings on Windows
Update the Windows "PATH" environment variable
Close VS Code and reopen it
```